# AIX services logging

Tags: services, aix

I have created sample subsystem for service as this:

```
mkssys -s  testService -p /usr/opt/myscript -a "-n" -u -R -S -f 9 -n 15
```

Now when I start it via :

```
startsrc -s testService
```

I get the message:

```
0513-059 The testService Subsystem has been started. Subsystem PID is 9437320.
```

The result of `lssrc -a` for the service after the start  is :

```
testService   inoperative
```

However the service doesn't seem to be working so I guess an error occurred. Where can I find the logs on why the service didn't start?

Comment: Here's some suggestions about debugging your script: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/frequently-repeated-question-request-problems-4175605430/#post5707383

Answer (score 1):

The System Resource Controller (SRC) system does not store any logs on its own. If your script produced any stdout, it will be [directed to /dev/console](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_72/m_commands/mkssys.html) unless you direct it otherwise with the `-o` option. Since you did not provide a `-o` option when you ran `mkssys`, you could run `alog -f /var/adm/ras/conslog -o` to see if your script produced any such output. Above and beyond that, since you appear to be calling a script, simply edit that script to direct logs anywhere you'd like.