# AIX + mkssys stdout to my own file = always empty file

Tags: services, aix

I used `mkssys -s service -p $BIN -u 0 -S -n15 -f9 -o /var/log/stdout -e /var/log/stderr` to specify my own console and error log files and they are always empty (though the file itself is created automatically). And alog complains:

> alog -t /var/log/console -o 0526-003
> alog: /var/log/console is not an alog type.

If I send it to /dev/console, then if I do

> alog -f /var/adm/ras/conslog -o:

I get the segfault that I want to capture. In Console, I don't see what process caused the fault though.

> Caught signal = 0 Sun Jun 28 17:36:39 CDT 2020 11 0 Sun Jun 28 17:36:39 CDT 2020 , code = 0 Sun Jun 28 17:36:39 CDT 2020 4569529040 0 Sun Jun 28 17:36:39 CDT 2020 , exiting application 0 Sun Jun 28 17:36:39 CDT 2020 +++PARALLEL TOOLS CONSORTIUM LIGHTWEIGHT COREFILE FORMAT version 1.0 0 Sun Jun 28 17:36:39 CDT 2020 +++LCB 1.0 Sun Jun 28 17:36:39 2020 Generated by IBM AIX 7.2 0 Sun Jun 28 17:36:39 CDT 2020 # +++ID Node 0 Process 5243226 Thread 2 0 Sun Jun 28 17:36:39 CDT 2020 ***FAULT "SIGSEGV - Segmentation violation" 0 Sun Jun 28 17:36:39 CDT 2020 +++STACK 0 Sun Jun 28 17:36:39
> CDT 2020 __fd_poll : 0x000000b4 0 Sun Jun 28 17:36:39 CDT 2020 _ZN6apache6thrift9transport13TServerSocket10acceptImplEv : 0x0000007c 0 Sun Jun 28 17:36:39 CDT 2020
> _ZN6apache6thrift6server16TServerFramework5serveEv : 0x000002d4 0 Sun Jun 28 17:36:39 CDT 2020 _ZN6apache6thrift6server15TThreadedServer5serveEv : 0x00000020 0 Sun Jun 28 17:36:39 CDT 2020
> _ZN5utils6thrift6Server5ServeEv : 0x0000002c 0 Sun Jun 28 17:36:39 CDT 2020
> _ZNSt6thread5_ImplISt12_Bind_simpleIFSt7_Mem_fnIMN5utils6thrift6ServerEFvvEEPS5_EEE6_M_runEv : 0x00000078 0 Sun Jun 28 17:36:39 CDT 2020 execute_native_thread_routine : 0x00000040 0 Sun Jun 28 17:36:39 CDT 2020 _pthread_body : 0x000000e8 0 Sun Jun 28 17:36:39 CDT 2020 ---STACK 0 Sun Jun 28 17:36:39 CDT 2020 ---ID Node 0 Process 5243226 Thread 2 0
> Sun Jun 28 17:36:39 CDT 2020 # +++ID Node 0 Process 5243226 Thread 1 0
> Sun Jun 28 17:36:39 CDT 2020 +++STACK 0 Sun Jun 28 17:36:39 CDT 2020 # At location 0x0000000000000000 but procedure information unavailable. 0
> Sun Jun 28 17:36:39 CDT 2020 ---STACK 0 Sun Jun 28 17:36:39 CDT 2020 ---ID Node 0 Process 5243226 Thread 1 0 Sun Jun 28 17:36:39 CDT 2020 ---LCB

How do I capture segfault messages into a file? Thanks

This question seems relevant: [AIX services logging](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/563633/420164)

Comment: Just to be sure, you started your service with `startsrc` after defining it with `mkssys`? Perhaps you can show the corresponding `lssrc -s service` output indicating that it's running?

Answer (score 0):

- Unless your program is writing to an alog (ie. using alog mechanism to write them) - forget about `alog`.
- On AIX there is a built-in mechanism to divert/copy all information written to `/dev/console` to the alog -t console
- The `mkssys` -o and -e arguments are regular files. It is up to your application to actually write to either of these files. Your application/service determines if the information is text or binary.
- As to identifying the process with the segfault - that might be reported to `errpt`. I know core dumps usually are, so I would expect a *segfault* to also be registered there.
- Here is an example of an `errpt` report. Notice **SIGNAL NUMBER** and **PROGRAM NAME**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
LABEL:          CORE_DUMP
IDENTIFIER:     A924A5FC

Date/Time:       Thu Feb 24 21:48:27 CUT 2022
Sequence Number: 1754
Machine Id:      00FAC25F4B00
Node Id:         aix2
Class:           S
Type:            PERM
WPAR:            Global
Resource Name:   SYSPROC

Description
SOFTWARE PROGRAM ABNORMALLY TERMINATED

Probable Causes
SOFTWARE PROGRAM

User Causes
USER GENERATED SIGNAL

        Recommended Actions
        CORRECT THEN RETRY

Failure Causes
SOFTWARE PROGRAM

        Recommended Actions
        RERUN THE APPLICATION PROGRAM
        IF PROBLEM PERSISTS THEN DO THE FOLLOWING
        CONTACT APPROPRIATE SERVICE REPRESENTATIVE

Detail Data
SIGNAL NUMBER
          11
USER'S PROCESS ID:
              18612646
FILE SYSTEM SERIAL NUMBER
           1
INODE NUMBER
                     2
CORE FILE NAME
//core
PROGRAM NAME
ksh
```

Hope this helps.